orden de lista y corchetes
soy bastante nuevo en este tema de jupyter notebook y me estan saliendo 2 errores
a. cuando creo una lista de 4 nombre la ejecuto y despues la leo no aparecen en ese mismo orden
b. cuando quiero seleccionar un solo elemento de esa lista me arroja el error como se ve en la imagen
sé que es algo muy básico, pero como les digo estoy muy muy verde, de antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar


Un listado, sin índices, entre llaves {v1, v2, ...} es lo que se conoce como set, es diferente a un diccionario {k1:v1, k2:v2, ...}. Estos no están ordenados y no se puede repetir un valor. Para acceder a sus elementos debes recorrerlos con un ciclo. Si quieres usar una estructura tradicional indexada y que no se cambien de posición usa listas [v1, v2, ...] o tuplas (v1, v2, ...).

amigo muchas muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya vi mi error nuevamente gracias y perdón por mi novatada

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

@aeportugal si el AP edita la pregunta para poner el código como texto, tú debieras publicar lo que pusiste en comentarios como respuesta.

@jachguate lo pensé, pero esto es una característica del lenguaje, no un problema en si. Y bueno, acá no gustan mucho del "farmeo de puntos".

@aeportugal, desde mi punto de vista, es una pregunta válida de un novato que bien merece una respuesta, que queda luego a disposición de otros novatos que estén investigando sobre el tema. No es farmeo de puntos, el sitio no se trata de resolver problemas, sino de responder preguntas bien formuladas y, con ello, construir una base de conocimiento en español sobre la programación en general.

Lo que pasa es que no estas declarando una lista debido a que en tu código donde estas asignando la variable esta entre llaves, declarándola como otro tipo de variables en Python se usan las llaves para declarar los diccionarios.
Para poder corregir esto debes de cambiar a corchetes, como se muestra a continuación:
paises_1=['Estados unidos','Chile','España','China']

Con esta modificación te permitirá realizar todo el código que habías puesto.

